# How exactly should I approach this problem?

Tags: linear-algebra

I've been asked to solve this problem:

> Let n be a number between 100 and 999 (inclusive). The sum its 3
>   digits, multiplied by 15, will be equal to the number itself, n. To
>   which of these 4 intervals does n belong to?
>
> 1. Between 100 and 150
> 2. Between 150 and 200
> 3. Between 500 and 550
> 4. Between 200 and 250.

This was my attempt.

Let $n=100n_1+10n_2+n_3$, where $n_1$ is the first digit, $n_2$ the second, and $n_3$ the third.

The condition given by the problem can be written as: $$15(n_1+n_2+n_3)=100n_1+10n_2+n_3$$ $$\boxed{85n_1-5n_2-14n_3=0}$$

Is it possible to find $n$, prove that its value is unique in the interval [100, 999], and ultimately find the right answer (a, b, c or d)?

The answer shouldn't take more than 2 or 3 minutes to find, according to my professor. But I'm still guessing. Any hints that push me in the right direction will be very welcomed.

**EDIT**

---

It looks like my professor rearranged the above formula this way: $$85\,n_1=5\,n_2+14\,n_3$$
and argued that $n_1$ **needs** to be 1 (but I don't understand how this is so evident for him, since at first sight there could be some $n_2$ and $n_3$ that made $n_1=2$ possible. Of course, $n_1\leq 2$ anyway, because $5·9+14·9<85·3$). From there, he just said $y=3$ and $z=5$ without further explanations. Either this guy is a genius (no way I could've ever solved it in 2 minutes), or he is lying about time completion!

Comment: Well, think about the scale.  The biggest the sum of the digits could be is $27$ and $15\times 27=405$.  So that helps immediately...keep going with that sort of reasoning.

Comment: I don't see any deep theory here, but there are not that many options --- multiples of 15 are, in the first category, just 150,135,120 and 105; (10,9,8 and 7 times 15) but then 135 satisfies 1+3+5=9.

Comment: Second $n_1$ in boxed equation should be $n_3$. Also, reduce it mod $9$ for additional information.

Comment: Since 135 is obviously a solution, it can be only case 1 (if the problem has a unique solution at all). But the problem is too silly to waste even two or three minutes on it.

Comment: Try $n_1=1,2,3...$. For $n_1=1$ you have $85-5n_2-14n_3$. So $85-5n_2$ has to be divisible by $14$. Thus $n_2=3$ and $n_3=5$. You´ll see that for $n_1>1$ it doesn´t work.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales It took me 2-3 minutes to understand your solution, but am not sure how to find it quickly ;)

Comment: Thank you guys. I edited the question to add my professor solution, which was hidden among other math papers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $85n_1-5n_2-14n_3=0$, then $5(17n_1-n_2)=14n_3$ so $n_3$ must be divisible by $5$. So, $n_3$ is either $0$ or $5$. If we set $n_3=0$, we would have $85n_1-5n_2=0$. However, since the lowest value of $n_1$ is $1$ and the highest value of $n_2$ is $9$, we must have $85n_1-5n_2\geq40$ so $n_3$ can't be $0$. Hence, $n_3=5$ and the problem becomes $85n_1-5n_2=70$, which leads us to the solution.

Comment: Thanks! I edited the question to add my professor solution (which was hidden among mountains of other math papers).

Answer (score 1):

\begin{eqnarray} 85n_1-5n_2-14n_3&=&0\\
4n_1+4n_2+4n_3&=&0\pmod 9\\
n_1+n_2+n_3&=&0\pmod 9
\end{eqnarray}

So the sum of the digits is divisible by $9$

\begin{eqnarray} 85n_1-5n_2-14n_3&=&0\\
n_3&=&0\pmod 5\\
\end{eqnarray}

So $n_3=0$ or $n_3=5$.

If $n_3=0$ then
\begin{eqnarray} 85n_1-5n_2&=&0\\
17n_1=n_2
\end{eqnarray}

which is impossible. So $n_3=5$.

\begin{eqnarray} 85n_1-5n_2-14n_3&=&0\\
85n_1-5n_2&=&70\\
17n_1-n_2&=&14\\
17n_1=n_2+14&\le23
\end{eqnarray}

So $n_1=1$

Since $n_1+n_2+n_3$ is a multiple of $9$ then $n_2=3$.

So $n=135$.